# Horizontal button group in Flutter

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart

I am trying to build a horizontal button group using flutter but the I didn't get as far as desired, I am new when it comes to building UIs using dart, how can I tweak the code to achieve the desired result ?

Below you will find my current progress and the desired result!

**current row of buttons**

```
//Horizontal buttons row    
            Wrap(                  
              direction: Axis.horizontal,
              children: <Widget>[
                ButtonTheme(
                  minWidth: 40.0,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text("A"),
                  ),
                ),
                ButtonTheme(
                  minWidth: 40.0,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text("B"),
                  ),
                ),
                ButtonTheme(
                  minWidth: 40.0,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text("C"),
                  ),
                ),
                ButtonTheme(
                  minWidth: 40.0,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text("D"),
                  ),
                ),
                ButtonTheme(
                  minWidth: 40.0,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text("E"),
                  ),
                ),
                ButtonTheme(
                  minWidth: 40.0,                     
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text("F"),
                  ),
                ),
                ButtonTheme(
                  minWidth: 40.0,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text("G"),
                  ),
                ),                        
              ],
            )
```

given result:
[image]

**desired result**
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how I did it:

```
Widget specialCharsPanel() {
  return Container(
    child: Material(
      elevation: 4.0,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(6.0)),
      child: Wrap( 
        direction: Axis.horizontal,                    
        children: <Widget>[
          SpecialChar("A"),
          SpecialChar("B"),
          SpecialChar("C"),
          SpecialChar("D"),
          SpecialChar("E"),
          SpecialChar("F"),
          SpecialChar("G"),                 
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 8):

you could use ToggleButtons that is more accesible and compatible with tabindex in web and desktop https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ToggleButtons-class.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kVEguaQWGAY

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your `RaisedButton` with `Container` instead of `ButtonTheme`, that will give you your desired output.